# Using BTN8962TA to implement 3 phase synchronous rectifier

Tags: rectifier, h-bridge

I want to use three BTN8962TA ([datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTN8962TA-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433fa9412f013fbe2d247a7bf5)) to implement a 3 phase synchronous rectifier. The input will be a BLCD motor used as a generator. The current at each phase will be measured with external precision shunt resistors and differential amplifiers, so I don't need the current measurement feature the BTN8962TA provides, I will only use the \$I_s\$ pin to detect failures.

The main difference between my scenario and the one considered in the datasheet/application notes is that the current will circulate in the "opposite direction" in the high-side MOSFET (i.e. where \$I_L\$ is measured). This is because I'm not using the BTN8962TA to drive a motor but to rectify the power from a generator.

I would like to know if the IC will classify this reverse current as a "fault" scenario and, in general, if this IC is usable in my scenario.

Comment: Make it easy for those you are asking to help you. [Edit] your question and add datasheet links to any devices you've mentioned. Use the Hyperlink button or Ctrl-L.

Comment: My understanding from reading the datasheet is, that this reverse current will be ignored and a failure will not be recognized. However, the added offset in the IS output let me assume, that reverse currents can be measured.